# Using a subprogram as a parameter to another subprogram

Tags: c++

I have a program here that doesn't compile. I get the following error messages:

```
main.cpp:55:26: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int, int)’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   55 |     cout << buns_on_tray(number_of_buns,tray_height,tray_width);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                          |
      |                          int (*)(int, int)
main.cpp:21:29: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int buns_on_tray(int, int, int)’
   21 | int buns_on_tray (int const number_of_buns,
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I wonder if this is because I am using my subprogram `number_of_buns` as a parameter on my other subprogram `buns_on_tray`. Is it not possible to use another subprogram as a potential parameter?

This is my code:

```
int number_of_buns (int const dough_weight,
                    int const weight_per_bun)
{
    return (dough_weight / weight_per_bun);
}

int buns_on_tray (int const number_of_buns, 
                  int const tray_height,
                  int const tray_width)
{
    if (number_of_buns <= (tray_height * tray_width))
    {
        return (number_of_buns);
    }
    
    else
    {
        return (tray_height * tray_width);
    }
}

int main()
{
  int dough_weight {};
  int weight_per_bun {};
  int tray_height {};
  int tray_width {};
  char gram {};
  char x {};
  
    cout << "Mata in degvikt: ";
    cin >> dough_weight >> gram;
    
    cout << "Mata in bullvikt: ";
    cin >> weight_per_bun >> gram;
    
    cout << "Mata in bakplåtsstorlek: ";
    cin >> tray_height >> x >> tray_width; 
    
    //cout << number_of_buns(dough_weight,weight_per_bun);
    cout << buns_on_tray(number_of_buns,tray_height,tray_width);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `cout << buns_on_tray (number_of_buns (dough_weight, weight_per_bun), tray_height, tray_width)`?

Comment: Anyway, by the time I'm done, there will be several less buns on the tray :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a **lambda** as a parameter to a function.  Using your code as an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

namespace {

int number_of_buns (int const dough_weight,
                    int const weight_per_bun)
{
    return dough_weight / weight_per_bun;
}

template <typename FN>
int buns_on_tray (FN number_of_buns,
                  int const tray_height,
                  int const tray_width)
{
    // alternative implementation:
    // return std::min(number_of_buns(), tray_height * tray_width);

    if (number_of_buns() <= (tray_height * tray_width)) {
        return number_of_buns();
    } else {
        return tray_height * tray_width;
    }
}

} // anon

int main() {
    int dough_weight {};
    int weight_per_bun {};
    int tray_height {};
    int tray_width {};
    char gram {};
    char x {};

    cout << "Mata in degvikt: ";
    cin >> dough_weight >> gram;

    cout << "Mata in bullvikt: ";
    cin >> weight_per_bun >> gram;

    cout << "Mata in bakplåtsstorlek: ";
    cin >> tray_height >> x >> tray_width;

    //cout << number_of_buns(dough_weight, weight_per_bun);
    auto fn = [dough_weight, weight_per_bun]{ return number_of_buns(dough_weight, weight_per_bun); };
    cout << buns_on_tray(fn, tray_height, tray_width) << "\n";
}
```